# Create methods like .ToString()

Tags: c#

I want to create my own methods like `.ToString()` which I want to use on my own project.

For example `ToDecimalOrZero()` which I want to convert the data into decimal, or if the data is empty convert it to zero.

I know I shouldn't ask for codes here, but I don't have the slightest idea how I can do that.

Can anyone help me out? Or at least refer me somewhere... I'm kinda lost. Thanks :)

Comment: Google for "Extension methods".

Comment: `I know I shouldn't ask for codes in here` precisely :)

Comment: I think your question is a bit vague. Do you mean you want to add these methods to an existing type, or are you looking for a way to create methods in general?

Comment: You should read a good book on C#. Your local library will have a few I guess.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth thank you, I didn't even know they're called "Extension Methods".

Comment: @walther It's a way of saying "i'm sorry" :)

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde I'm looking a way to create my own methods. Found it btw thanks for you time :)

Comment: @Etrit: I figured - that's why I posted my comment. I had the feeling you are eager to learn but missing the right keyword.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use extension methods:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static decimal ToDecimalOrZero(this String str)
        {
            decimal dec = 0;
            Decimal.TryParse(str, out dec);
            return dec;
        }
    }   
}

using ExtensionMethods;
//...
decimal dec = "154".ToDecimalOrZero(); //dec == 154
decimal dec = "foobar".ToDecimalOrZero(); //dec == 0
```

Answer (score 11):

Here an example of how to write your own **extension methods**

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int WordCount(this String str)
        {
            return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' }, 
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
        }
    }   
}
```

*from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)*

Note that extension methods have to be **static**, as well as the class that contains extension methods